# List A value compared to all possible in List B

Tags: c#, linq

Pardon my asking about lists twice in one day, folks. I'm comparing two lists and need a bool back - do they match or not? I have List B I'm comparing in its entirety to a single value from List A. I've tried a few combinations but no luck.

Here's a little code for your trouble:

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.QuizQuestions.Count(); i++)
    {
 for (int j = 0; j < Model.QuizQuestions.ElementAt(i).QuizAnswers.Count(); j++)
        {


            if (Model.QuizHeader.QuizQuestions.Any(item => item.QuizAnswers.Any(x =>x.AnswerID == Model.QuizQuestions.ElementAt(i).QuizAnswers.ElementAt(j).AnswerID)))
            {
                   //Do something here
            }

            else
            {
                //Do something else
            }


        }
```

What obvious thing am I missing? Thanks!

ViewModel:

```
public class QuizIndScoreReportObject
{
    [NotMapped]
    public virtual TopicList Topic { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual QuizHeader QuizHeader { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual List<QuizQuestions> QuizQuestions { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual List<QuizAnswers> QuizAnswer { get; set; }
}
```

Note QuizAnswers is a property of QuizQuestions. QuizQuestions are a property of QuizHeader. I'm passing two both lists under this configuration, so I apologize for the lack of clarity there.

Comment: could you provide your model?

Comment: Done. It's a ViewModel.

Comment: So you want to know if some value x from List A is present in List B? Or do you want to know if all values from A are present in B and all in B are present in A?

Comment: @Thaoden I'd like to know if Value X from List A is present somewhere in B.

Comment: Then why not use `A.Contains(B)`? I have a feeling I'm missing something...

Comment: Does QuizQuestions contain a list of QuizAnswers?

Comment: @Thaoden In this case that's why I went with .Any(), since it's a linq expression that appears to be better suited and lambda compatible, in my tiny speck of knowledge.

Comment: @kryptonkal Yes. In this view model there are two lists under separate instances.

Comment: Still not sure what you want to achieve... My best guess is `if(model.Any(m => m.QuizQuestions.QuizAnwers.Contains(QuizAnswer))`.

Comment: Can you show the `QuizQuestion` and `QuizAnswer` classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your help everyone. I was able to modify my code to do what I needed with some tinkering. Here's what wound up working, via an intermediate variable.

```
                var value = Model.QuizQuestions.ElementAt(i).QuizAnswers.ElementAt(j).AnswerID;
            if ( Model.QuizHeader.QuizQuestions.Any(item => item.QuizAnswers.Any( x=> x.AnswerID == value)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is a bit of a simplistic view of things but have you tried the intersect and except functions built into the Linq library?

```
int[] seq1 = { 1, 2, 3 }, seq2 = { 3, 4, 5 };

seq1.Intersect (seq2).Dump ("Intersect");
seq1.Except    (seq2).Dump ("seq1.Except (seq2)");
seq2.Except    (seq1).Dump ("seq2.Except (seq1)");
```

The results would be as follows:

- Intersect = (IEnumerable) 3;
- Seq1 = (IEnumerable) { 1, 2 };
- Seq2 = (IEnumerable) { 4, 5 };

Could you do something like this with your QuizQuestions?  Are the Id's that you are looking for in each class unique or does Id 1 from List A match Id 2 from List B?  It is not clear to me the structure of the QuizQuestion class so I'm not sure how to help you further.

Comment: That's the path I wanted to take but Intersect doesn't seem to return a bool as far as I can tell. So I can't if(List1.Intersect(List2)) in this case. Also, they're unique IDs, except the match.

Comment: Will you always need to do something with each set or only the matches?

Comment: I'll use the data from List A if there's a match by marking a checkbox. If there's no match, the html should render without the checbox. So I won't need List B after the comparison,

Comment: So to be clear you are only rendering the "matches" or those that intersect correct?

Comment: Not even that, just getting a true or false if they even have a match.